# Possible ways to read data from a .sqlite file into web page

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app where the data is populated into .sqlite file. That .sqlite file is then pulled from device to work station to keep records for the future. For that I am  thinking to make a web page where the .sqlite file is browsed and after that display all the data into the web page. Is it possible to do what I am thinking? If yes, how? Could anybody guide me to approach the goal? Thanks in advance.

Note: I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Search for Webservice and study it. You do not actually need to pull .sqlite file from device everytime. you can directly send data from your application.

Comment: @Kedarnath You are right but my app has to work without internet connection. I cannot change my mind. I can use SQLite browser but I wont be available to work on it. So I want to make some nice GUI in webpage to read and record those data for normal people also.

Comment: You can do it without Internet connection. You can use cost free Bluetooth or Wifi Connection :)

Comment: @Kedarnath How is it possible to use Bluetooth for sharing data in web from android app?

Comment: For that your desktop or laptop should have Bluetooth connection too.

Comment: @Kedarnath This way is too messy in the situation where I am. I am just wondering if php script can read and write the .sqlite file.

Comment: Wifi is better solution than Bluetooth, then you can access your pc just like local computer. Only you need to start xamp in your pc and you can access it from phone when you are in limited range.

Comment: I am sure this propose will be rejected because of security issue in the place. Some other ways??

Comment: then your manual way to attach the device with pc and pull out db is fine. for this you need to create your db outside the package.

Comment: @Kedarnath that's what I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sqlite in you Web, only you need a correct driver.

For example, if you web use PHP:

`$db = sqlite_open('myfile.sqlite', 0666, $sqliteerror);
    $result = sqlite_query($db, 'select * from foo');
    var_dump(sqlite_fetch_array($result));`

Comment: I reviewed many drivers. It's hard to choose as I am the new using these drivers. Could you please suggest me any reliable driver for abstraction layer?

Comment: in PHP. But I decided to use PDO anyway. Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: System Architecture]

I am trying this way. Hopefully it will work. If not please show me the path.